# Regular Expression that matches text between a specific string and a character

Tags: regex

I have a problem that I can't seem to find an answer to online. I have some text:

`Variable1 = Value1, Variable2 = Value2, Variable3 = Value3, Variable4 = Value4,`

Lets say the string I want to find is `"Variable2 = "`

I want `"Value2"` returned. It can't include the comma.

So far the best I could come up with is:

`(Variable2)\s\=\s(.+?),`

But this returns `Variable2 = Value2,`

**Additional Info**

I'm stuck using a program called Automate BPA. It has some built in support for regex.

I hope it's possible and I appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. In addition, please take the time to share the steps you've taken so far to research or resolve things on your own.

Comment: We need to know what language this is in.  We'd like to know http://www.whathaveyoutried.com? Maybe you should consider a http://www.sscce.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a look behind and a look ahead around your target:

```
(?<=Variable2\s?=\s?).+?(?=,|$)
```

The look ahead matches on comma or end of input, so it will still match the last term if you search for that.

Answer (score 0):

`$var = 'Variable1 = Value1, Variable2 = Value2, Variable3 = Value3, Variable4 = Value4,';`

`$new = preg_split( '/,/', $var);`

`print_r($new);`

That will break it up into an indexed array

`Array ( [0] => Variable1 = Value1 [1] => Variable2 = Value2 [2] => Variable3 = Value3 [3] => Variable4 = Value4 [4] => )`

Comment: Sure, if you're in PHP.  If you're using, say, bash, that will cause errors.

Comment: I can only use regex and it has to match just the text after the = and before the comma for a specific variable.

Comment: What Language though?

Comment: I'm stuck using an obscure automating software that has some built in regex support

Comment: @rangers8905 - Not all Regular expressions are created equal.  We need to know if you're using PCRE, or ECMA Standard, or POSIX ERE, or what.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html  If you tell us which language you're using, we can get you a step closer.